# Javascript Regex multiple search in two words

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to transfer the results between Regex and two words to an array, but unfortunately I couldn't this. Can you help me?

In this text

```
[row]
Row text1
[rowEnd]

[row]
Row text2
[rowEnd]
```

I will search this content,

```
[row]
(.*)
[rowEnd]
```

Based on this I write a regex like this

```
/(\[row\]+)(.*)(\[rowEnd\])/gs
```

However, this way, it takes the whole, not piece by piece.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript, you could use

```
^\[row]\r?\n([^]*?)\r?\n\[rowEnd]
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\[row]\r?\n` Match `[row]` and a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^]*?` Match 0+ times any char including a newline non greedy
- `)` Close group 1
- `\r?\n\[rowEnd]` Match a newline and `[rowEnd]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RDZWpY/1)

```js
const regex = /^\[row]\r?\n([^]*?)\r?\n\[rowEnd]/gm;
const str = `[row]
Row text1
[rowEnd]

[row]
Row text2
[rowEnd]`;

Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => console.log(m[1]));
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about `[^]`. Every time I come across your answers on [tag:regex], I learn something new. Keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

#### Without RegEx

- Split the data by `"[row]"`.
- Then filter those strings which end with `"[rowEnd]"`.
- Finally remove `"[rowEnd]"` from the filtered strings.

```js
const 
  data = "[row]Row text1[rowEnd][row]Row text2[rowEnd]",
  res = data
    .split("[row]")
    .filter((s) => s.endsWith("[rowEnd]"))
    .map((s) => s.slice(0, -8));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: As another way this works too. Thanks!